# Even with gecko driver, the entered URL is not loading

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Only a blank page is displayed after loading the URL.

Maven Framework using

- Firefox version : 49.x
- Selenium driver version : 3.4.0

code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D://SW//geckodriver//geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.qaz.com");
```

Comment: update firefox browser to 53.x and gecko driver too

Answer (score 0):

Use single forward slash "/" or double backward "\" in path. Try this code it is working fine on Firefox version 49.0 and Selenium 3.4.0 jars

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:/software and tools/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.qaz.com");
```

if still facing the problem, Please let me know.